# How to find "partial" solutions in a underdetermined system of linear equations?

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra

Let's say I have this matrix:

1 1 1 | 1 
 0 0 1 | 1

This system obviously has infinite solutions.

x1 = -x2 
 x3 = 1

x1 is dependent upon x2 and x2 is free, but what I'm interested in is x3. 
Is there an algorithm that can find a solution that would look something like this: [NaN, NaN, 1] for x1, x2 and x3?

My guess would be that you could use a variation of the gauss elimination algorithm, but I am not really sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that a system has at least one solution (you can check it using standard Gaussian elimination).

Lemma: the value of a variable is fixed if and only if it's the only variable in the row in the reduced row echelon form.

Proof:
If it's the only variable in the row, it must be zero for any solution of the homogeneous system. Thus, it's a constant for the original system.

If it's not the only variable in the row, its value is not fixed. Indeed, the other variable in the row is free, so we can choose it's value arbitrarily. Two different choices of this free variable give two different values of the pivot variable.

So the final solution looks like this:

1. Get the reduced row echelon form of the matrix using Gaussian elimination.
2. Check if there's at least one solution. If there isn't return something.
3. Return a vector containing the value of the variable if it's the only variable in the row and `Nan` otherwise.

In your case, the reduced echelon form is:

```
1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1
```

The last variable has a unique value 1. The second variable is free. The first variable is not the only one in its row. Thus, the result is `[Nan, Nan, 3]`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reply. So, let me get this straight: If I have determined the reduced row echelon form of my matrix, then, if there's only one 1 in a row, the corresponding variable must have a fixed value, if there are more 1s there is no solution for every variable having a 1 in that row?

Comment: @Fullk33 If no solution means infinitely many solutions, than you're right.